# How to create a list using a family tree in DrRacket

Tags: scheme, racket

I have this family tree, and I want to extract a list with the names of all people who have blue eyes.

But I keep getting a list of lists instead:

```
'((("george") ())
  ("joseph")
  ())



(define-struct node (name birth eyes father mother)) 

(define family (make-node "camille" 2015 "brown"
                           (make-node "mark" 1988 "brown"
                                      (make-node "george" 1963 "blue" empty empty)
                                      (make-node "lisa" 1965 "brown" empty empty))
                           (make-node "jessica" 1990 "black"
                                      (make-node "joseph" 1959 "blue" empty empty)
                                      (make-node "Rebecca" 1964 "black" empty empty))))



(define (col-eyes fam color)
  (cond
    [(empty? fam) empty]
    [(equal? (node-eyes fam) color)
     (cons (node-name fam)
       (append (col-eyes (node-father fam) color)
               (col-eyes (node-mother fam) color)))]
    [else (cons (col-eyes (node-father fam) color)
                (col-eyes (node-mother fam) color))]
    ))

(col-eyes family "blue")
```

This is what I want: `'("george" "joseph")`, can someone please help? Thank you.

Comment: You click the delete link in the post to delete. You need to be logged in and do it from a browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure which Scheme you're using so I cannot test this, but you probably want an `append` in place of the last `cons`:

```
(define (col-eyes fam color)
  (cond
    [(empty? fam) empty]
    [(equal? (node-eyes fam) color)
     (cons (node-name fam)
       (append (col-eyes (node-father fam) color)
               (col-eyes (node-mother fam) color)))]
; right here v
    [else (append (col-eyes (node-father fam) color)
                  (col-eyes (node-mother fam) color))]))
```

Comment: Thank you very much! it was very useful!